# Are there any downsides to cheaper biodegradable degreasers?

Tags: maintenance, cleaning

I’m after a cheaper (than the bike-specific brands) biodegradable degreaser for cleaning my bike chain.

I have found a few which are apparently biodegradable, however, I’m wondering if there is anything about non-bike-specific degreasers that could cause any damage to the bike?

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to the site.  I've edited out the product reference to make the question more generalised, avoiding product recommendations. I hope it's still in the spirit of your question, please [edit] if you want to.

Comment: Not part of the question, but the more aggressive cleaners can cause damage to the user, via skin contact, or fumes in the eyes/airways.

Answer (score 5):

I use a generic citrus degreaser from Home Depot (largest home improvement stores) that costs $2.99 a bottle. Works fine, does not damage the bike.

Answer (score 3):

This question came up recently in [Lennard Zinn's Technical Q&A column](https://www.velonews.com/2005/11/gear/technical-faq/technical-qa-with-lennard-zinn-not-so-simple-green-2_9216). Apparently if you leave a part in Simple Green (the degreaser he specifically discussed) for a very long time, the metal can deteriorate. But this is a matter of weeks or months. If you rinse off your chain the same day, it won't be a problem.

Comment: It's [hydrogen embrittlemen or stress cracking corrosion](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple+green+hydrogen+embrittlement).  Because of the way chain side plates are manufactured, they're quite susceptible to hydrogen embrittlement.  Simple Green even offers [a product specifically designed not to cause hydrogen embrittlement](https://simplegreen.com/en-au/industrial/products/extreme-aircraft-precision-cleaner/)

Answer (score 1):

The ones available around here , at least, seem to be generally less effective than the bike ones on a per-unit-volume basis, so you might need to use a bit more, but it certainly shouldn't do any damage (which would tend to result from them  being too strong).